# Get template block contents and call from ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I'm using django 1.9 and python 3. My english also isn't the best, so excuse the question if it is formulated bad.

I'm working on making my website a single-page application. I need to get the `{% block %}` contents of a given template, and then send that as a HttpResponse so that ajax can pick it up and inject it into the page.

I've tried using the answer from this question: [Django - how to get the contents of a {% block %} tag from a template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758443/django-how-to-get-the-contents-of-a-block-tag-from-a-template)

But upon trying to fetch the contents of a block in my view like so:

```
response_data[content] = get_block_source('profile/login.html', 'content')
        
        if request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

I just get this error from django, no matter what I do:

> ValueError at /login/ Template block content not found

The contents of the block don't even make it to the ajax call, what gives?

## EDIT:

I'll include my "content" block here:

in my template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="big-title text">Log in</div>
<div class="form-container">
    <form name="login-form" id="user" method="post" action="/login/" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="text">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="title">Enter your credentials</div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-flex">
                <div class="field-container">
                    <div class="field-input-container">
                        <div class="field-label accent">Username</div>
                        <div class="field-input">
                            <input class="field-input-element" type="text" name="username" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-help">Your username is always lowercase.</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-flex">
                <div class="field-container" style="height: 110px">
                    <div class="field-input-container">
                        <div class="field-label accent">Password</div>
                        <div class="field-input">
                            <input class="field-input-element" type="password" name="password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field-help"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-button-container">
    <div class="form-error"></div>
    <div class="form-message"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Accept" class="button form-button"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

In my base (base.html)

```
<body>
    <div id="modal-container">
        <div id="modal-overlay">
            <div id="modal-items">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <div id="header-title" class="text accent">App name</div>
            <div id="header-nav">
                <nav>
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <a href="/" class="text accent">Home</a>
                    <a href="/feed" class="text accent">Feed</a> {% if request.user.is_superuser %}
                    <a href="/admin" class="text accent">Admin</a> {% endif %}
                    <a href="" class="text">N</a>
                    <a href="/{{ request.user }}" class="header-avatar-small-a">
                        <div class="text header-greeting">Hi, {{ user.userprofile.display_name }}</div>
                        <div class="header-avatar-small">
                            {% if not user.userprofile.avatar == '' %}
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}users/{{ user }}/avatar" alt=""> {% else %}
                            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}users/avatar" alt=""> {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    {% else %}
                    <a href="/login" class="text accent">Log in</a>
                    <a href="/register" class="text accent">Create account</a> {% endif %}
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="progress">
                <div id="header-progress" class="fill"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main>
            {% block content %} {% endblock %}
        </main>
        <footer></footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you define a block called content with {% block  content %} in your template?

Comment: Of course. Both in my base.html and the template I am trying to fetch from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template source is the template actual HTML, not the file reference

Comment: Ah, I see. I'm not gonna paste the entire html into the function however, what would be the most efficient way of handling this? Trying to be DRY here.

Comment: split only the element you need into another html, pass this code to the function, and use include in the templates

Comment: what if the html is dynamic (ie model based variables)

Comment: There are solutions, like render these partial templates, then pass the rendered code. But be careful, otherwise you will go to the rabbit hole of building another framework. It's the same question django faces: block, templates, dynamic templates etc.

Comment: I see, I really just want to make my application single-page, so I figured this wouldn't be too hard with django. I am gonna have to lookup how to render partials first and then pass the code, if there's not an easier way, maybe? my goal is that since this website is audio based, there has to be a way for the audio to not stop playing when you navigate.

Comment: I've been linked to that so many times. It just won't install. I get the same `egg_info error 1` everytime I try. It sucks because that looks like it could really solve my predicament.

Comment: I know, but look at the code, or other pjax implementations, for the idea. Either the server sends complete HTML snippets, or just data and client side js renders the page

Comment: wait, so I can send a TemplateResponse, and ajax could pick it up?

Comment: Yes, in the jQuery ajax you get success function which receives the data. If the data is HTML, then put it in some element  `success:function(data){$("#someElement").html(data);}`

Comment: Alright, so how can I tell my views to send the rendered blocks? so for example, if I send it using json, I could have one response_data = {} dictionary and then for block1, I could send response_data[block1] = "block1 html", and response_data[block2] = "block2 html" and then inject the respective code into the page, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Render the template with `django.template.loader.render_to_string()`, and then send the string to the client, and inject it in place

Comment: I'm trying to move this discussion to chat, but it's failing. Would you be interested in helping me more over a chat room? I really appreciate all the help, as I am new to this.

Comment: Ok move this to chat

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103532/discussion-between-sebastian-olsen-and-aviah-laor

Comment: can't login to the chat

Comment: That's weird, does it give you any message?

Comment: just says "login to talk", which I did, twice, on Chrome, Safari and FF

Comment: Hmm. Probably a bug in which the devs will get to. Alright, so now I have django.template.loader.render_to_string(), and it works and gives me the whole rendered template but I would like it to only give me the contents of my blocks, since injecting the header and footer when it is already included seems dumb to me.